# How can I add a button to each list view item with Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added a join button next to each group as follows:

```
var publicGroupItems = publicGroups.map(group =>
            <ListItem key={group._id} global href={'/groups/' + group._id} image={group.imageUrl} title={group.name} ><button type="button" onClick={this.joinGroup(group._id)}>joinGroup</button></ListItem>)
```

When I click on the button it goes through each of the groups ids and adds the current user to ALL groups.

How can I make it so that the user is only added to the specific group where I clicked join?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the future when posting questions, please make sure to properly format your code using the `{ }` code formatting option.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is your `onClick`

```
onClick={this.joinGroup(group._id)}
```

Since you have `this.joinGroup(group._id)` as a function call, it will be called once for each group **before** the button is even clicked.

You need to reference your function instead of calling it:

```
onClick={this.joinGroup.bind(this, group._id)}
```

This will trigger `joinGroup` when the button is clicked. The first argument will be the value of `group._id` and the second will be the [SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

```
joinGroup: function(groupId, event) {
  //Join The Group
}
```